# How to remove sticky error message being overlayed on all screens of ubuntu, the message is displayed on all screens even after restarting?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I was installing some extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/ that extensions had some dependencies which was not met and hence it dumped an error message on my screen

"
System Infromations - Desktop Widget
Please Install:
libgtop, Netowrk Manager and gir bindings on ubuntu: git1.2-gtop-2.0, git1.2-networkManager-glib-devel on Arch: libgtop, networkmanager on openSUSE: typelib-1_0-GTop-2_0, typelib-1_0-NetworkManager-1_0
"

This message was dumped on my screen (overlay on all screens), this is not being erased after rebooting the system. How to remove this error message?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Forcefully killing gnome shell solved the problem

`killall -3 gnome-shell`